# I just put too much air and tired popped can i fix it with bike patch i never patched bike before

Tags: repair

**I put to much air in my bike tire and popped it can a bike**repair patch kit fix because I never patched so bike before

Comment: Probably not, patches cover small puncture holes, when you blow out a tire by over inflating the inner tube will often have a large rip in it and need to be replaced.  No way to know without taking it off and adding a picture of where the innertube failed.

Comment: Ooo yeah thanks if I take a picture of it will you help me determine if it's patch worthy or not

Comment: @Affe It might be worse than that; if the tire had a wire bead and the pressure blew it right off the rim it might have damaged the rim too.

Comment: Lol naw it didn't do all that but thanks for future reference ..it just loud pop noise.@it ranged my ears

Comment: Clarify please - did you pop the tube or the tyre?

Comment: Are you sure you actually over-inflated it? Was it flat or very under-inflated before? Might have pinched the tube somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repair large holes in inner tubes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13729/how-to-repair-large-holes-in-inner-tubes)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is almost definitely not.  There are basically 2 ways your tire can fail by over-pressurizing it; either you blew the bead off the rim or you tore the tire.

In the former case you need to make sure that it didn't damage the bead or the rim (the latter is not likely, but [has happened](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/56332/43557)).  If the bead is damaged you'll want a new tire; even if this one still works at lower pressures, you've compromised its safety margin.

The latter, more likely, case is that you tore the tire somewhere, almost definitely on the sidewall.  Unlike a puncture, which is a small point-like hole, a tear like this in the fabric of the tire isn't a simple patch job.  A small (short) gash in the sidewall can be temporarily patched with a [tire boot](https://www.parktool.com/product/emergency-tire-boot-tb-2), which is reasonable for use in an emergency (as are comparable patches, like a piece of cardboard, etc.) but not recommended for on-going use.  However a tear from the sidewall failing under pressure is unlikely to be short; once a rip starts, it will likely be several centimetres long before the pressure is relieved.  It's not possible to say exactly, but I'd estimate anything over 3 cm long is unlikely to be safely patched (at all).

Basically, if you blew out a tire you should replace it.  And if it blew off the rim, instead of tearing, you need to check the rim for damage too (and possibly replace it).  You can do this by spinning the rim and making sure there are no deviations from a planar circle.  If you don't have rim brakes you can do this with a piece of chalk taped to the seat stay.

(Note, I had a *rim* fail on me - it basically wore down enough along the braking track that it folded over under pressure from the tire - and it *still* damaged the bead of the tire when it blew off.  Not enough to make it unworkable, but enough that I put a new tire on the new rim.)

Comment: It's also possible that they didn't actually cause the problem by overpressure but that the tube was caught between the rim and the bead or that the tube was twisted in some other way before being inflated. It might also be the case that insufficient rim tape caused the tire to blow out. Any of these things could result in the tire popping once brought up to higher pressure. If they are stating that both the tire and rim are fine, then it's likely that there was something else that puncture the tube.

Comment: @Kibbee Fair enough; I guess I hung up on "popped the *tire*" and didn't consider that an unexperienced cyclist might have conflated the tire and the tube.